# Confusion with implicit equation of straight line

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, analytic-geometry, graphing-functions

I'm getting started with 2D graphics. I've read that a straight line can be expressed as the following implicit equation.

$\vec{N} \cdot \vec{L} + d = 0$

Where, $\vec{N}$ is normal vector and $\vec{L}$ is the position vector for a point on the line. I have confusion with $d$. Is it the distance of the line from the origin *along* the normal vector or *against* the normal vector? In other words, for a straight line $\{4\hat x,5\hat y\} \cdot \vec{L} + 4 = 0$ what will be the correct graphical representation, left one or the right one?

[image: d is along the normal]
[image: d is against the normal]

The greenish blue line is the normal and the red one is the intended straight line drawn with cairo-graphics and GTK+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$\vec L$ is a generic vector $(x,y)^T$.  Lock at what becomes your equation if $ d=0$, than do the same with a $d \ne 0$.

---

If $\vec N=(4,5)^T$ ( as in your example) , than for $d=0$ the equation becomes 
$ 4x+5y=0$ that, as you noted, is the equation of a line that passes thorough the origin since $(0,0)$ satisfies it.

If $d \ne 0$ the equation becomes $4x+5y+d=0$ ad you can see the for $x=0$ the equation is satisfied if $y=-d/5$ so the line intersect the $y$ axis at the point $(0,-d/5)$. In the same way you can find the intercept of the line with the $x$ axis that is $(-d/4,0)$.

If $\vec N=(a,b)$ is  a unitary vector ( i.e. $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=1$) than $|d|$ is the distance of the line from the origin.

This is the simpler interpretation of $d$.

Comment: The line will pass though origin if $d$ becomes 0, because then the position vector of any point on the line is perpendicular to the normal vector. But how does that help me finding whether $d$ is calculated along or against the normal? Sorry but I'm new to these.

Comment: I've added something to my answer. I hope it's useful.

Comment: I'm struggling with the interpretation here :( that means if $d=4$ the line should pass through $(0, -0.8)$ and $(-1,0)$, but the distance of that line from the origin is not 4, so is $d$ not the distance of the line from the origin? Or is that normalized co-ordinate?

Comment: $|d|$ is the distance of the line from the origin only if $|\vec N|=1$ ( added to the answer).

Comment: So a normalized normal makes $d$ the desired distance against the normal from the origin. Thanks, help much appreciated. Plotting is easier with the slope-intercept form as you mentioned.